# Bang! - Eliminating an outlaw with backfire

Tags: bang

The outlaw has only one life and bangs the sheriff. The Sheriff plays a 'backfire' card, eliminating the outlaw from the game.

Does the sheriff receive the 3 cards since the player was not eliminated with a bang card?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the Backfire card is part of the Valley of Shadows expansion...?

If that is correct, then this product description geeklist from boardgamegeek, states that the outlaw is now the target of a Bang! and thus eliminated by a Bang!

https://boardgamegeek.com/geeklist/205880/item/4492671#item4492671

(And this question seems to have a duplicate : [Bang! Elimination Award For Henry Block and Backfire](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/43022/bang-elimination-award-for-henry-block-and-backfire)
They seems to have been created almost simultaneously )